# Ошибка при вычислении суммы ряда

Tags: c++, c++builder, ряды

По заданию нужно было найти сумму ряда ((-1)<sup>(n-1)</sup>*x<sup>(2n-1)</sup>)/(4<sup>n</sup>*(2n-1))
Вот такое получилось. Но при к=2 и 3 и х=2 и 3 сумма ряда равна 0. не могли бы посмотреть и сказать если что-то где то не так?

```
#include <conio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
long Sum=0;
double n=1;
int k;
double x;
        char answer;
        answer = 'y';
        while (answer =='y')
        {
                cout << "vvedite k : ";
                cin >> k;
                cout << "vvedite x : ";
                cin >> x;
                for (Sum=0 , n=1 ; n <= k ; n++ )
                {
                        Sum +=( pow ( -1.0 , n-1 )*pow ( x , 2.0*n-1))/ (pow ( 4.0 , n) *(2.0*n-1));
                }
                cout << "Summa = " << Sum << endl;
                cout << "Pos4itat' ewe raz? y/n\n";
                cin >> answer;
        }
        getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Оффтопик: в C++ не надо определять все переменные в начале функции. Даже наоборот -- хорошим тоном считается определять переменную как можно ближе к первому использованию.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы зачем-то пишете ответ в long, тогда как результат представляет собой double. При значения k <= 3  сумма получается меньше единицы, поэтому при приведении к long вы получаете ноль.И еще - не пишите транслитом. Лучше учите английский